# automatically create an email address for my domain name

Tags: php, asp.net, exchange-server, email

I want to create a website which will automatically create an email address for my domain name whenever my visitor opts for my product. I had tried with manually but it is a TDS work so I want to automate the same.

> ### for eg:
>
> adam123 signs up to my member's site.
>   The website should run a script where the email address is created automatically. 
>   Email to adam123@my-domain.com goes to johns email address: adam123@hotmail.com and mymail@my-domain.com

Comment: You  need to provide code of what you've tried already. We wont do all the work for you. Show us what you attempted so far, why it didn't workt etc

Comment: I had tried using below,

<pre> INSERT INTO emailtable (Customer-email, Email) VALUES ("adam123@my-domain.com","mymail@my-domain") <code>

Comment: Put that into your main post, and I believe people will need a little more info but that's a start!

Comment: To create an email address via code, you must have a remote call to mail server. If using any control panels like cpanel, you have better ways by invoking execution urls by appending the user's name and domain into the URL or else if you are using a bare mail server without control panel, you better need a solution for various steps to create a mailbox at once.

Answer (score 1):

To create an email address and a forwarder you need to have access to the underplaying administrator API from your email environment. Depending on your hoster this might not be possible and there might be legal security reasons why this isn´t possible. Additional you might need a special API to control the unterlaying email environment and there is no general one. As you didn´t specify which email environment you are using its not really possible to provide you something.

So for example if your server is running Plesk you might wish to try to use the [Plesk API](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/api-rpc/about-xml-api.28709/) and the [manage email API](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/api-rpc/reference/managing-mail.34477/) from it.